# How to mock generics within method parameters

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito

I have the following method in an interface:

```
<T extends RequestSource> CompletableFuture<PaymentResponse> requestAsync(PaymentRequest<T> paymentRequest, String idempotencyKey);
```

And have the following line in my test case so that i can mock the method:

`when(client.requestAsync(Mockito.any(), eq(request.getIdempotencyKey()))).thenReturn(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(pResponse.from(pProcessed)));`

But i get the following:

```
You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
    when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use
```

It seems to me that the Mockito.any() is not a suitable but I'm not sure what to put in it. Any suggestions?

Comment: the wrong argument matcher  seems to be the eq(...). Try to replace it with a String of your choice.

Comment: Are you sure you're correctly setting up the mock?

Comment: I can't reproduce this from the code given and my own stubs for the missing types. Please provide a complete [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).